# Snowflake check query status fail with no default role

Tags: http-post, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, http-get

I am trying to design an executeQuerySynchronously() method. I first execute the query by make a POST request to execute the query Asynchronously, which returns a response including the statementhandle of that execution. I then keeps checking the status of that query by making a GET request to that statementHandle.

I was able to make the POST request, a response was successfully returned. However, I couldn’t make the GET request. And I got this error: “No default role has been assigned to the user, contact a local system administrator to assign a default role and retry.”

My question is:
1.Does a GET request absolutely need the role specified? If so, there’s nothing documented on Snowflake SQL API about specifying a role. The POST request has documentation however on specifying the role in request body. Or is it automatically assumed to use the default role?

2.Or is this error caused by other reason?

3.How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The user executing the query on Snowflake must have a role, either implicitly as their default role or defined explicitl

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! In the POST request that executes the query, I was able to pass in my role in the request body. However, there’s no place for me to pass in a role when I make the GET request to check the status. Do you know how to specify the role in this case?

Comment: Never tried this I'm afraid. Why not resolve the issue by setting a default role for your user - rather than trying to figure out the API issue?